# SwiftUI - How do I make edit rows in a list?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I'd like to use the EditButton() to toggle edit mode, and have my list rows switch to edit mode. I want to include a new button in edit mode for opening a modal. I can't even get the EditMode value to switch the row content at all.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    @Environment(\.editMode) var isEditMode

    var sampleData = ["Hello", "This is a row", "So is this"]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {

            List(sampleData, id: \.self) { rowValue in
                if (self.isEditMode?.value == .active) {
                    Text("now is edit mode")  // this is never displayed
                } else  {
                    Text(rowValue)
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Edit A Table?"), displayMode: .inline)
            .navigationBarItems(trailing:
                EditButton()
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need to set the environment value for editMode in the List:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isEditMode: EditMode = .inactive

    var sampleData = ["Hello", "This is a row", "So is this"]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(sampleData, id: \.self) { rowValue in
                if (self.isEditMode == .active) {
                    Text("now is edit mode")
                } else  {
                    Text(rowValue)
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Edit A Table?"), displayMode: .inline)
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: EditButton())
            .environment(\.editMode, self.$isEditMode)
        }
    }
}
```

You need to be careful, and make sure `.environment(\.editMode, self.$isEditMode)` comes after `.navigationBarItems(trailing: EditButton())`.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that this approach works because the editMode environment var is initially set with a Binding to a State var which also ends up receiving the changes to the environment var made by the EditButton? If so, this is a very useful tool.

Comment: @ChuckH yeap, that is basically what it does.;-)

Answer (score 7):

Adding to @kontiki answer, if you prefer using a boolean value for editMode so it is easier to modify, use this `@State` variable:

```
@State var editMode: Bool = false
```

And modify the `.environment` modifier to this:

```
.environment(\.editMode, .constant(self.editMode ? EditMode.active : EditMode.inactive))
```

Now switching to/from edit mode with your own button is as easy as:

```
Button(action: {
    self.editMode = !self.editMode
}, label: {
    Text(!self.editMode ? "Edit" : "Done")
})
```