# Edit mode in a List

Tags: swiftui

Updated with working code.

I've implemented a List in my app with Edit mode, so I can move the rows by dragging a row handle. That works fine, but doesn't look too good, since the move icon is placed under the content of the row (see screen dump). And that is because Edit mode makes room for a delete button.

Is there a way to hide elements in the row when you're in Edit mode?

[image: Row in a list in Edit mode]

The code for the View is:

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine
import DateHelper

struct EggList: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var egg : Egg
    @State private var eggs = Egg.all()

    @State private var editMode: EditMode = .inactive

    var body: some View {

        NavigationView {

            List {

                Image("Pantanal")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(height: 250)

                ForEach(eggs) { eggItem in
                    NavigationLink(destination: EggDayList(eggItem: eggItem)) {
                        CellRow(eggItem: eggItem)
                        .environment(\.editMode, self.$editMode)
                    }
                 }
                .onDelete(perform: delete)
                .onMove(perform: move)
            }

            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Eggs"), displayMode: .inline)
            .navigationBarItems(leading: EditButton(), trailing: NavigationLink(destination: Settings()){
                Text("Add Egg")})
            .environment(\.editMode, self.$editMode)
        }
    }
    func delete(at offsets: IndexSet) {
        eggs.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
    }
    func move(from source: IndexSet, to destination: Int) {
        eggs.move(fromOffsets: source, toOffset: destination)
    } 

}

struct CellRow: View {

    let eggItem: Egg
    @Environment(\.editMode) private var editMode

    var body: some View {

        HStack(spacing: 8) {

            Image(eggItem.species)
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 48, height: 48)
                .clipShape(Circle())

            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
                Text("\(eggItem.species)")
                    .font(.footnote)
                    .lineLimit(1)
                    .padding(.top, -4)

                Text("id-"+String(eggItem.eggNumber))
                    .font(.footnote)
                    .lineLimit(1)
                    .padding(0)

                Text("\(eggItem.layDate.string(with: "dd-MM-yy"))")
                    .font(.footnote)
                    .lineLimit(1)
                    .padding(.bottom, -7)
            }.frame(width: 90, alignment: .leading)

            VStack(spacing: 2) {
                Text("days")
                    .font(.footnote)
                    .padding(.top, 12)
                Image(systemName: "\(eggItem.diffToday)"+".circle")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 40, height: 30)
                    .padding(.bottom, 12)
                    .foregroundColor(.red)
            }.frame(width: 50, alignment: .leading)

            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                Text("prediction")
                    .font(.footnote)
                    .padding(.top, 14)
                Text(formatVar1(getal: eggItem.calcWeights[eggItem.daysToPip-1].prediction)+"%")
                    .font(.title)
                    .padding(.bottom, 12)
            }.frame(width: 80, alignment: .leading)

            if !(self.editMode?.wrappedValue.isEditing ?? false) {
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
                    Text("INC")
                        .font(.footnote)
                        .lineLimit(1)
                        .padding(.top, -4)
                    Text("37.3")
                        .font(.footnote)
                        .lineLimit(1)
                        .padding(0)
                    Text("30%")
                        .font(.footnote)
                        .lineLimit(1)
                        .padding(.bottom, -7)
                }
                .frame(width: 30, alignment: .leading)
            }

            Spacer()

            VStack(alignment: .trailing, spacing: 0) {

                Image(systemName: "info.circle")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 22, height: 22)
                    .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
                    .onTapGesture(count: 1) {
                        print("action")
                }
            }

        }
        .listRowInsets(.init(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
        .frame(height: 46, alignment: .leading)
        .padding(0)
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you have hardcoded the demotions of elements, so the cell cannot resize for editing. You can hide elements while editing. Can you shared some code, please? It would be much easier to explain how to achieve it.

Comment: As requested...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is, that the `editMode` variable does not change when you press the EditButton. No matter in what state, in your CellRow the `editMode` variable always returns `.inactive`. I don't know why, it could be a bug.
I had the same problem, but I found this question here: [SwiftUI - How do I make edit rows in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57496453/swiftui-how-do-i-make-edit-rows-in-a-list), which uses a workaround by passing the `editMode` environment value into a private `@State` variable, which seems to work perfect.

So here is what you need to do:

- Add `@State private var editMode: EditMode = .inactive` to your EggList view.

  > This creates a state variable that from now on holds the editing mode.
- Add `.environment(\.editMode, self.$editMode)` somewhere after the `.navigationBarItems(...)`.

  > This sets the environment variable `editMode` in `EggList` to a binding of the state variable above.
- Add `.environment(\.editMode, self.$editMode)` directly after the `CellRow(...)` initializer.

  > This inserts the state variable `editMode` into the environment of `CellRow`, where it can be accessed via `@Environment(\.editMode)`.

Now you can just wrap one of your elements in an if-statement to hide it when in editing mode:

```swift
if !self.editMode?.wrappedValue.isEditing ?? true {
    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
        Text("INC")
            .font(.footnote)
            .lineLimit(1)
            .padding(.top, -4)
        Text("37.3")
            .font(.footnote)
            .lineLimit(1)
            .padding(0)
        Text("30%")
            .font(.footnote)
            .lineLimit(1)
            .padding(.bottom, -7)
    }
    .frame(width: 30, alignment: .leading)
}
```

or, if you prefer, continue using the `isHidden` extension from LuLuGaGa:
`.isHidden(self.editMode?.wrappedValue.isEditing ?? false)`

Comment: Guess you mean:  @State private var isEditMode: EditMode = .inactive

Comment: Thanks for the correction. But it still throws an error.

Comment: Error at .environment(\.editMode, self.$editMode). Error is Value of type 'EggList' has no member '$editMode'.

Comment: I can test it myself tomorrow and see if I get the error too.

Comment: Guess it is because the editMode private var is only known within the Cellrow struct. And not in the EggList struct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200899/discussion-between-arakweker-and-icomputerfreak).

Answer (score 1):

Add a little extension to View:

```
extension View {

    func isHidden(_ hidden: Bool) -> some View {
        if hidden {
            return AnyView(self.hidden())
        } else {
            return AnyView(self)
        }

    }

}
```

Next add @Enviroment to your CellRow:

```
@Environment(\.editMode) var editMode: Binding<EditMode>?
```

You will be able to add a modifier:

```
.isHidden(editMode?.wrappedValue.isEditing ?? false)
```

to one of the stacks that you think is the least important.

Comment: That sounds exactly like what I want... but something is going wrong. When I tap the 'Edit' button, I see a 'rebuilt' and the 'Edit' button text changes to 'Done'. That's it... I don't see the delete icon in front of the row, nor do I see the row handle. And the stack with the .ishidden modifier is still there.

Comment: I would need to see your code for the View where the list is declared to be able to help.